# Change/remove ID and then jquery function

Tags: jquery

I've a jquery function which works on a specific ID that belongs to an input.

Based on scrolling and calculating the offset, I remove ID attribute of the field and give it to another one. But the problem is, the main jquery function doesn't work on the new field which will have the same ID.

All I encountered with was about DOM which doesn't change so I wrapped that jquery function with `jQuery("body").on('change', '#s', function() { ... });` but with no effect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider using a JSFiddle.net to show us what you are doing. That might help us see what you have for code and issues.

Comment: What makes you think it's a good idea to move an ID to another element, have you ever seen that in a tutorial or anywhere else on the web ?

Comment: @Daved that custom function belongs to a class within a large js file so I can't make a live demo.

Comment: **which has the same ID** this thing rings all my brain alarm bells. same `id`?? `id` should be unique

Comment: @adeneo Based on what's needed and what I should do, that's the case I'm dealing with.

Comment: what's the new field you are moving this ID to? does the element trigger the change event?

Answer (score 0):

moving around the `id` is not the right way IMHO. Use a `class` instead. Have a look [**at this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RgST5/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input id="chosenone" class="colored" value="I hold the ID" />
<input id="givemetheid" value="I do not hold the ID :(" />
<button id="btn">Move ID</button>
```

**JS**

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    console.log("ok");
    $("#chosenone").toggleClass("colored");
    $("#givemetheid").toggleClass("colored");
});

$(document).on("change", ".colored", function(){
    alert("hello");   
});
```

hope it helps (code updated)

Comment: please change .change to .click. its wrong to attach .change event to button